# How do I select a browser version with testcafe CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, testcafe

While trying to run testcafe against ie using this command:

`testcafe ie src/tests/**/*`

testcafe runs Internet Explorer 7.0 / Windows 10. Since I don't have IE7 on my Windows 10 machine I have determined that what this really means is IE11 run in IE5 document mode. The test hangs and eventually crashes.

Is there a way I can specify IE11 so that the tests run with the correct document mode?

Answer (score 0):

Extract from doc : https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/browsers/browser-support.html#officially-supported-browsers

> The list of all the available browsers can be obtained by calling the
>   testcafe command with the --list-browsers flag.
>
> To run tests in a different local browser, specify the path to the
>   browser executable file.

So Just give the executable path of the browser you wanna use

Comment: IE11 is running from the correct path. When it is launched, the document mode is automatically set to IE5. I will try this explicit path method anyways though.

Comment: using `testcafe 'path:\`C:\Program Files\internet explorer\iexplorer.exe\`' src/tests/reviewModal/*` results in an error 'Error: The specified browser name is not valid!' although it matches the format shown in the documentation.

Comment: @Rorschach120  In Windows cmd.exe (default command prompt), use double quotation marks:

Comment: Using Bash and have read the docs up and down for information like this.